# Rails SQL Injection safe SELECT fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

I have the following ruby On Rails code:

```
#The user can only ask for a subset of the following columns:
authorized_fields= ["id","created_at","updated_at"]

#The user sends the requested columns as a comma separated string in the fields param
fields = (params[:fields].split(',') & authorized_fields).join(",");

#Build the query to be run:
sql = "SELECT json_agg(u) FROM (SELECT #{fields} FROM table_name) u"

#Run the query against the database
ModelName.connection.select_value(sql)
```

My question is, is this query SQL Injection safe? My understanding is that since I limit the available fields, so it protects me from injections.

Am I correct? Can someone give me an example of a `fields` parameter sent by the user which will not be safe?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name`. Code should be like this:

```
input_fields = params[:fields].split(',').collect do |field| 
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name(field) 
end
```